# How to send access token in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I have been asked to testing of the node module, So we have a post request which gives us access token.

```
  it('GET accesstoken', (done) => {
        request(URL)
            .post('/oauth/login')
            .set('accept', '/application/json')
            .type('form')
            .send(data)
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) return done(err);
                expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
                expect(res.body.access_token).to.be.a('string');
                accessToken = res.body.access_token;
                done();
            });
    });
```

Now, the access token we get from here is something we need to use here

```
 it('GET /users/:id/activities/', (done) => {
        request(URL)
            .get('/users/5aa1736a64bf0a423ae4d191/activities/')
            .set('accept', '/application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken)
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                done();
            });
    });
```

I am using postman and I am unable to figure out how can we send access token in headers of our get request.

[Update] THis is what i am getting from my previous request

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.36CgBmDIcPmYmN1aB3XCIJFmzqs4KpeuLb9miPQqIns","refresh_token":"775f341af178cca24bd183fad4bf760b461cd985","accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.36CgBmDIcPmYmN1aB3XCIJFmzqs4KpeuLb9miPQqIns"}
```

From this I copied just the access token and leaving everything else

```
access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.36CgBmDIcPmYmN1aB3XCIJFmzqs4KpeuLb9miPQqIns","refresh_token":"775f341af178cca24bd183fad4bf760b461cd985","accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

In the get request, `Headers` I added `Auth` and in the value I added `Bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.36CgBmDIcPmYmN1aB3XCIJFmzqs4KpeuLb9miPQqIns`

Answer (score 3):

inside `Headers` tab, enter the following key and value:

```
{
  key: 'Authorization',
  value: 'Bearer xxxx'
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this but didn't worked (updated my question)

Comment: @KuchBhi, are you sure that the access token is a valid one?

Answer (score 2):

Following the [Postman documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) on authorization you set it under the authorization **tab type -> Bearer Token -> Enter token**.

If you want to store the token automatically after sending the get access token request you can make use of environment variables, [here's a good guide](https://medium.com/@codebyjeff/using-postman-environment-variables-auth-tokens-ea9c4fe9d3d7).

Answer (score 2):

In headers tab of postman just add `Authorization` and in value `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.36CgBmDIcPmYmN1aB3XCIJFmzqs4KpeuLb9miPQqIns","refresh_token":"775f341af178cca24bd183fad4bf760b461cd985` Bearer word is not needed.Even after that this issue persist try adding your accessToken along with your request like this `/users/5aa1736a64bf0a423ae4d191/activities/ ? access_token=`